# drawing vertical and horizontal lines using jquery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

How can i draw vertical and horizontal line using jquery mobile and also make it responsive? Here is my link http://jsfiddle.net/sanand29/uh35s9vn/    `enter code here`
    `
 The vertical line is not coming where as it should be there and also the horizontal line is not responsive. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a reference to jQuery. The $('#line').animate is a jQuery function.

```
$('#line').animate({
    height: 234
}, 1000);
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/uh35s9vn/1/)**

Comment: thanks buddy i got my answer,, i think same process can be applied and likewise six divisions can be made as 2 are already done..